# Remember selected checkboxes - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, search, checkbox

At first, all checkboxes are checked.
Then i'm just checking 2 of them and press search.

Checkboxes and Search-Button:

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="stat2" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="ts.status.check2" />&nbsp;
  <label for="stat2">Status 2</label>
  <br />

  <input type="checkbox" id="stat3" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="ts.status.check3" />&nbsp;
  <label for="stat3">Status 3</label>
  <br/>

  <input type="checkbox" id="stat1" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="ts.status.check1" />&nbsp;
  <label for="stat1">Status 1</label>
  <br />

  <input type="checkbox" id="stat4" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="ts.status.check4" />&nbsp;
  <label for="stat4">Status 4</label>
  <br />
```

And then a new page (new URL) is loading, on this page there is a 'back' button.
When i press the back button, i'm getting back to the first page, and alle 4 checkboxes are selected again, how can i make it possible, that only the ones are checked, which i checked first?

Back-Button

```
  <div class="btn-group container panel-footer">
    <button type="button" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;" class="btn">Back</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: store checkboxes in $rootScope

Comment: @ShubhamKandiyal isn't deprecated? For me you should prefer route param (UI Router or native router)

Comment: $rootScope or localStorage for persistence.

Answer (score 0):

**Use $rootScope for maintaining your data:**

```
$rootScope.checkState = {
    check1: true,
    check2: false,
    check3: true,
    check4: false
};
```

And then in your view:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="stat2" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="$root.checkState.check1" />&nbsp;
```

(Do this for all your checkboxes with the according field)